# Testing update user using Devise and TestCase (Rails 4.1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, minitest, testcase

I am trying to test, updating a User with devise strong params.

Strong params are set in the application controller:

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) do |u|
  u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password,
           :time_zone)
  end
```

The Registrations Controller update action is:

```
def update
  user_update_params = devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:account_update)
  ....
  @user = User.find(current_user.id)
  ....
  @user.update(user_update_params)
  ...
end
```

In my test I am passing update attributes:

```
def update_attributes
  {user: {email: 'bob@home.com',
  time_zone: 'Melbourne'}}
end

test 'Update' do
  patch(:update, update_attributes)
  assert_equal 'bob@home.com', assigns(:user).email
  assert_equal 'false', assigns(:user).use_weighted_rates
end
```

The problem is the Devise::ParameterSanitizer object @params reflects the @user  attributes, not the update_attributes:

```
@params=
  {"user"=>
    {"email"=>"john@home.com",
     "time_zone"=>"Sydney"}}
```

So the test assertions fail.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: The test is not passing: 

assert_equal 'bob@home.com', assigns(:user).email

Minitest::Assertion: Expected: "bob@home.com"
  Actual: "john@home.com"

The problems is that user_update_params are:

 {"email"=>"john@home.com", "time_zone"=>"Sydney"}

Comment: What about when you change this line: "@user.update(user_update_params)" to "@user.update!(user_update_params)".  Does it raise an exception?

Comment: No, because there is no problem with the user_update_params. The problem is the devise sanitizer is returning the attributes from the user, not from the params passed to the controller

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the user was not signed in. I was creating a user using:
get(:create) to create a user on the create action of the controller. I changed this is to sign_in create(:user) using a user factory and all good.